# How can I use cookies across multiple Cypress tests?

Tags: javascript, cookies, cypress

I am using `cypress` to test my Register and Login forms. I want to set cookies in my `register.js` test and then make use of them in my `login.js` test.

I preserve the cookies in **cypress/support/index.js**:

```
Cypress.Cookies.defaults({
  preserve: ['test_email', 'test_password'],
});
```

My **register.js** test looks like this:

```
describe('Create new account', () => {
  it('Visit Register', () => {
    cy.visit(Cypress.env('URL_REGISTER'));

    cy.setCookie('test_email', 'fake@email.com');
    cy.setCookie('test_password', 'abc123');
  });

  it('Fill out register form', async () => {
    const email = await cy.getCookie('test_email');
    const password = await cy.getCookie('test_password');

    cy.get('[data-cy="register-email"]').type(email.value);
    cy.get('[data-cy="register-password"]').type(password.value);
  });
});
```

When I run this test, I get this error:

> Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

I understand that `cy.getCookie()` returns an object and is async, which is why I'm trying to use `await`, but for some reason, this doesn't seem to be working. How can I *set* and *get* cookies across multiple cypress tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preserve cookies between tests with [Cypress.preserveOnce()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/cookies#Preserve-Once), or in `beforeEach()` preserves for all tests.

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('test_email')
})

it('set cookie', async () => {
  cy.setCookie('test_email', 'fake@email.com')
})

it('once', async () => {
  const email = await cy.getCookie('test_email')
  expect(email).to.have.property('value', 'fake@email.com')  // passes
})

it('twice', async () => {
  const email = await cy.getCookie('test_email')
  expect(email).to.have.property('value', 'fake@email.com')  // passes
})

it('thrice', async () => {
  const email = await cy.getCookie('test_email')
  expect(email).to.have.property('value', 'fake@email.com')  // passes
})
```

---

You should stick with the documented way of using getCookie.

If I run

```js
const email = await cy.getCookie(...)
```

after a `cy.visit()`, I get undefined.

If I use

```js
cy.getCookie(...).then(...)
```

on the next line it gets the value.

Since Cypress has not documented the await syntax anywhere, you are likely to get some flaky results.

Standard pattern is:

```js
it('once', () => {
  cy.getCookie('test_email').then(email => {
    expect(email).to.have.property('value', 'fake@email.com')  // passes
  })
})
```

---

If you run tests in CI they may be run parallel, so better to setCookie in `before()` or `beforeEach()`.

```js
before(() => {
  cy.setCookie('test_email', 'fake@email.com')
})

beforeEach(() => {
  Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('test_email')
})

it('uses cookie once', () => {
  ...
})

it('uses cookie twice', () => {
  ...
})

it('uses cookie thrice', () => {
  ...
})
```

Comment: I'm using a global `Cypress.Cookies.defaults({preserve: ['test_email', 'test_password']});` in my `cypress/support/index.js`. I like the idea of moving the `setCookie` statements into `before()`. I tried using the conventional async method and it works when I run the test on it's own, but my next **login.js** test fails when I run both tests together. It's as if the register.js test doesn't run the same way when both tests are run together. It doesn't log the `type` events when run with the login.js test, but on its own, it does.

Comment: So, you already know how to use cookies across multiple Cypress tests.

Comment: You should definitely ditch the `const email = await cy.getCookie(...)`. If I run that after a `cy.visit()`, I get undefined, but if I `cy.getCookie(...).then(...)` on the next line it gets the value. Since Cypress has not documented the await syntax anywhere, you are rolling the dice.